# if $d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$,then $A-BCD$ is Trirectangular Tetrahedron.

Tags: geometry

> A  tetrahedron $A-BCD$,and let $$S_{ABC}=a,S_{ACD}=b,S_{ABD}=c,S_{BCD}=d$$
>   and such
>   $$d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$$

**show that:
then tetrahedron $A-BCD$ is Trirectangular Tetrahedron.**

[image]

**I know this reslut,if $A-BCD$ is Trirectangular Tetrahedron.then we have
$$d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$$
and I can prove this. But the inverse problem,I can't see it,and can't prove it.I hope someone can know? Thank you**

Comment: the $S$ are the areas of the indicated triangles?

Comment: @WillJagy,yes,Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to change your notation slightly, for better symmetry:
$$a = |\triangle BCD| \qquad b = |\triangle CDA| \qquad c = |\triangle DAB| \qquad d = |\triangle ABC|$$
(So, "$x$" is the area of the face opposite vertex "$X$".)

Consider this tetrahedral Law of Cosines for Faces:
$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 + d^2 - 2 c d \cos \angle AB - 2 d b \cos\angle AC - 2 b c \cos \angle AD$$
where "$\angle XY$" indicates the *dihedral angle* along edge $XY$.

Certainly, if the tetrahedron is tri-rectangular (what I call "right-corner") with hypotenuse-face $\triangle BCD$, then the cosines vanish and we have [de Gua's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem),
$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 + d^2 \qquad (\star)$$

However, the converse isn't true. Assuming $(\star)$, the Law of Cosines for Faces reduces to 
$$0 = c d \cos \angle AB + d b \cos\angle AC + b c \cos \angle AD$$
This relation can hold without the cosines simultaneously vanishing. (Contrast this with Law of Cosines for Triangles, which has just a single cosine term.) In fact, if you fix hypotenuse-face $\triangle BCD$, then $(\star)$ is (usually) satisfied by a continuum of tetrahedra with vertex $A$ on some ellipsoid.